# Increasing Angular Performance in Custom Angular Dropdown with Filtering Functionality with One Way Binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a custom angular component that works as a dropdown select element with filtering functionality. The input is a basic input element with several angular directives:

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-change="ctrl.filterTextChangeLocal($event)" ng-model="ctrl.ngModelValue" ng-click="ctrl.openDropdown($event)" />
```

The above input is responsible for opening the dropdown and allowing the user to type, as the user types the data in the dropdown element is filtered accordingly. The filtering is done in the controller with the basic angular filter:

```
 ctrl.filteredItems = ctrl.$filter("filter")(ctrl.items, ctrl.ngModelValue);
```

The dropdown element looks like this:

```
 <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th ng-repeat="heading in ctrl.gridColumnHeaders" class="text-center">{{heading}}</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="row in ctrl.filteredItems" ng-mousedown="ctrl.onSelectedLocal(row, $event)">
                <td ng-repeat="value in ctrl.sort(row) track by $index" class="text-center">
                    {{value}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

All works fine but the as the number of items passed into the component increases (100+ items) and the dropdown increases accordingly, the filtering is slow. Meaning as I type a character the filtering of the dropdown lags behind.

I understand Angular filters aren't the best performing but I believe the majority of the lag is coming from ng-repeat and the two-way binding. I can't create a one-way binding inside the ng-repeat itself as so:

```
  ng-repeat="value in ::ctrl.filteredItems"
```

because I lose the binding for the filtering. Will just setting a one-way binding on the value increase performance:

```
  {{::value}}
```

Or what's the best way to increase the performance here? Really need to try and stay with in the Angular framework so looking for an Angular solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to simply apply:

```
one-time-binding="true"
```

directly on the ng-repeat?

Usually a two-way-binding on 100+ elements should not hurt performance -
but if you have a nested loop inside your loop, then..

Comment: Thanks Reto..what do you mean directly on the ng-repeat? Inside the "tr" element? I've tried doing "item in ::ctrl.filteredItems" which should do the same thing shouldn't it? That loses the binding for filtering which I need.

Comment: Ok, then put it at least on the nested loop and on the repeat on the `th` element. The problem are the high number of watcher which are created for the two-way-.bindings. Do your items have unique properties, which you could use to track instead of their index?

Comment: Ok yeah I put it on the th and the td ng-repeat, and inside the angular expressions. Not sure what else there is to do..